# java jpa exception unique-constraint hibernate

Tags: java, exception, jpa

I would like to know how to return an object after using saveAll() method (from Spring JPA) with a unique constraint error.

For example, I have a list of objects. Each of them must have a unique field (for example, "phone_number" must be unique for each row in the table). I want to save these objects in Postgres DB, but two objects have the same "phone_number" value, so I catch an Exception. There is a text in this Exception (in "cause" field), and this text tells me what "phone_number" value was the cause of my problem. But it's not enough for me. I need other fields of this "problematic" object (it's like when we use save() method, we get a saved object in return).

I know that I can use save() method in For Loop, so my Exception will take an object as a parameter. But there are too many objects in my list at once, I don't think that it's a good idea to save them separately, so I use saveAll().

Comment: You could already apply a filter to your list and check if there are duplicate phone_number attributes in Java instead of SQL.